# How can I find the biggest two of the 10 numbers with the pointer?

Tags: c

What I want can be done with simple programs, but how can I do it with a pointer? I think I have a fault somewhere.

These are my entries.

```
3 4 8 1 6 9 7 2 5 2.
```

It is output.

```
1.major=0 2.major=0
```

my codes.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void func(int*major1,int*major2);
int main() {
    int major1,major2;
    func(&major1,&major2);
    printf("1.major=%d 2.major=%d",major1,major2);

    return 0;
}
void func(int*major1,int*major2){
    int array[10],i;
    
    *major1=0;
    *major2=0;  
    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
        printf("%d.number",i+1);
        scanf("%d",&array[i]);
        if(array[i]>major1){
            *major2=*major1;
            *major1=array[i];
            
            
        }
        else if(major2>major1) {
            *major2=array[i];
            }
        
    }
    
    
}
```

And error screen.

```
[Warning] comparison between pointer and integer
```

Comment: `if(array[i]>major1)` should be `if(array[i]> *major1)`

Comment: The warning is almost always rather an error.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This code can help you :

```
#include <stdio.h>

void func(int*major1,int*major2);

int main()
{
    int major1,major2;
    func(&major1 , &major2);
    return 0;
}

void func(int *major1,int *major2)
{
     int array[10];
    *major1=0,*major2=0;

    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        printf("%d.number :",i+1);
        scanf("%d",&array[i]);
        if(array[i]>*major1)
        {
             *major2=*major1;
             *major1=array[i];
        }
        if(array[i]>*major2&&*major1>array[i])
        {
            *major2=array[i];
        }
    }
    
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        if(array[i]>*major2&&*major1>array[i])
        {
              *major2=array[i];
        }
     }
    printf("\nThe first biggest number in this array is :%d",*major1);
    printf("\nThe second biggest number in this array is :%d\n",*major2);
}
```

Comment: regarding: `func(&major1 , &major2);`   where `func()` is being called, the variables `major1` and `major2` are already pointers.  so what is being passed to `func()` is two pointers to pointers rather than two pointers to `int`

Answer (score 3):

The warning is correct, on the lines where you compare `major1` and `major2,` you are lacking `*` in front (2 lines total). So all you references in `func` should be `*major1` and `*major2` to access the value behind the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

keep at this only

```
    if(array[i]>*major1) {
        *major2=*major1;
        *major1=array[i];
    }
```

Comment: this is only half of the fix, there is another problem just below what you pasted

Comment: It won't even come up as a warning because comparing pointers is perfectly legal

Comment: The other half should be `else if (array[i] > *major2) { *major2 = array[i]; }`.

Comment: Yes it worked thanks a lot.@starboy_jb   and I used what you said in the else if command, thanks to you.@Ian Abbott